# Prawn asset pipeline images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, prawn

I'm using RefineryCMS 2.1.2 and Prawn. I have a property engine in which I have properties with images. I can display these in the show template using `image_fu` but when I try and create my pdf with a picture like so

```
class Refinery::Properties::PropertyPdf <  Prawn::Document
  def initialize(property)
    super()
    image @property.property_images.first.image.url, fit: [300,300]
  end
end
```

I get this error

```
ArgumentError (/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTQvMDcvMTYvMTZfNTZfNDVfOTY3XzEuanBnIl1d/1.jpg not found):
  prawn (1.1.0) lib/prawn/images.rb:145:in `verify_and_open_image'
  prawn (1.1.0) lib/prawn/images.rb:79:in `build_image_object'
  prawn (1.1.0) lib/prawn/images.rb:67:in `image'
  vendor/extensions/properties/app/models/refinery/properties/property_pdf.rb:29:in `pictures'
  vendor/extensions/properties/app/models/refinery/properties/property_pdf.rb:9:in `initialize'
  vendor/extensions/properties/app/controllers/refinery/properties/properties_controller.rb:23:in `new'
  vendor/extensions/properties/app/controllers/refinery/properties/properties_controller.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in show'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:196:in `respond_to'
  vendor/extensions/properties/app/controllers/refinery/properties/properties_controller.rb:20:in `show'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__945948839670585827__process_action__3030439923241519075__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.1.221) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:38:in `block in process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.1.221) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:357:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.8.1.221) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:37:in
```

I've tried it in development & production mode on my computer and both have the same issue. If I look at `http://localhost:3000/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTQvMDcvMTYvMTZfNTZfNDVfOTY3XzEuanBnIl1d/1.jpg` I can see the image

In my production.rb I have the following

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

If I use the following it only works in development mode.

```
  image "public/system/refinery/images/#{first_image.image_uid}", fit: [300,300]
```

**Update**

Looks like RefineryCMS uses Dragonfly for storing images

https://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/urls/

It uses 'fog' to talk to the Amazon S3 storage.

I can use the following in Prawn to download a file from S3

```
require 'open-uri'
...
image open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/<my bucket>/2014/07/16/01/31/47/621/3.jpg")
```

This worked on my local machine running in production mode. Now I just need to find out how to get the S3 url for the image. If I deploy this code I get a HTTP 403 forbidden error as I'm trying to access the URL directly instead of my S3 session.

**Update**

Connecting through Fog fail because this is passing it the actual file and I think prawn image wants a path.

```
    con=Fog::Storage.new({provider: 'AWS', aws_access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'], aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']})
    d=con.directories.get("<my bucket>")
    file=d.files.get('2014/07/16/01/31/47/621/3.jpg')
    image file.body, fit:[30,30]
```

**Update: Messy solution**

Here is my current messy solution so that I can work in production & development environments. It works but it looks terrible.

```
images = @property.property_images.where("image_id > 0")
expire = (Time.now + 600).strftime('%s')

if ENV['RAILS_ENV']=="production"
  # Make a connection to Amazon S3 through Fog
  connection=Fog::Storage.new({provider: 'AWS', aws_access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'], aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']})
  dir=connection.directories.get("dcre_production")
end

if images.count > 0

  # Display a large first image.
  first_image = images.first.image
  unless first_image.nil?
    if ENV['RAILS_ENV']=="production"
      # Download the first image from Amazon S3
      file=dir.files.get(first_image.image_uid)
      image open(file.url(expire)), fit:[300,300]
    else
      # Get the first image from local drive
      image "public/system/refinery/images/#{first_image.image_uid}", fit: [300,300]
    end
  end

  # Display thumbnails underneath
  images.each do |property_image|
    unless property_image.image.nil? 
      unless property_image.image.image_uid == first_image
        if ENV['RAILS_ENV']=="production"
          file=dir.files.get(property_image.image.image_uid)
          image open(file.url(expire)), fit:[70,70]
        else
          filename = property_image.image.image_uid
          image "public/system/refinery/images/#{filename}", fit: [70,70]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there already a fog connection I could use within RefineryCMS?

Is there a nicer way to handle reading from local storage compared to S3 depending if I'm running production or not?

Comment: Hello, there is no way to include with prawn AWS Images?

Answer (score 8):

You need to give prawn the directory where your file is stored.
You can do something like this:

```
image = Rails.root.join('app','assets','images','image.jpg').to_s
```

Comment: I'm using heroku for my deployment and Amazon S3 for my files

Comment: I think you might need to copy the file locally in that case.  You can use [copy_to_local_file](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3:copy_to_local_file)

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the `images.rb:145` (https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/images.rb) from prawn, you'll see the following code:

```
  io_or_path = Pathname.new(io_or_path)
  raise ArgumentError, "#{io_or_path} not found" unless io_or_path.file?
  io = io_or_path.open('rb')
```

Here, it tries to open the image from the file system. I think some of your Prawn paths you provided are wrong, or missing. Hook into the images.rb with a debugger statement, and look at the value of the variables.